# Swift - Finding longest binary gap of a given integer

Tags: performance, algorithm, array, swift, complexity

I recently had the chance to try Codility's algorithm training, and the very first one in the list is [finding the longest binary gap of a given integer](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/1-iterations/binary_gap/).

I tried to implement this in Swift, and after finishing it up, I looked at answers all over the internet. My approach is a bit different from what I have seen from others.

---

**What is a Binary Gap?**

> A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the binary representation of N.
>
> For example, number **9** has binary representation `1001` and contains a binary gap of length **2**. The number **529** has binary representation `1000010001` and contains two binary gaps: one of length **4** and one of length **3**. The number **20** has binary representation `10100` and contains one binary gap of length **1**. The number **15** has binary representation `1111` and has no binary gaps. The number **32** has binary representation `100000` and has no binary gaps.

---

*The following is from the console which makes it easy to understand the implementation.*

```
Binary String of "1041" is: "10000010001"
Position of 1's: [0, 6, 10]
The longest binary gap is 5
```

**Basically what I am doing is:**

1. Iterating each binary character, and store the position/index of 1's in an array.
2. As I am looping through, I find the binary gap between two 1's by subtracting the current index of `1` with previous index of `1`, so that it gives me how many `0`'s are present in between them. I then decrement whatever value I get by 1 ('cause arrays...).
3. As I am looping through, I keep track of the longest binary gap in a variable.

The time complexity is **O(n)**, and I'd like to know if this approach is in any way efficient in terms of memory, or is there any scope of improvements with this? Thanks for your time.

---

**Code:**

```
public func getLongestBinaryGapFor(_ N : Int) -> Int {
    
    var arrayOfIndexes:[Int] = []
    let binaryString = String(N, radix:2)
    
    print("Binary String of \"\(N)\" is: \"\(binaryString)\"")
    
    var longestBinaryGap:Int = 0
    var index = 0
    
    for char in binaryString {
        if char == "1" {
            arrayOfIndexes.append(index)
            let currentBinaryGap = getCurrentBinaryGapFor(arrayOfIndexes)
            if arrayOfIndexes.count == 2 {
                longestBinaryGap = currentBinaryGap
            } else if index > 2 {
                if currentBinaryGap > longestBinaryGap {
                    longestBinaryGap = currentBinaryGap
                }
            }
        }
        index += 1
    }
    
    print("Position of 1's: \(arrayOfIndexes)")
    return longestBinaryGap
}

func getCurrentBinaryGapFor(_ array:[Int]) -> Int {
    var currentBinaryGap = 0
    if array.count >= 2 {
        let currentPosition = array.count - 1
        let previousPosition = currentPosition - 1
        currentBinaryGap = array[currentPosition] - array[previousPosition] - 1
        return currentBinaryGap
    } else {
        return currentBinaryGap
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Naming

According to the
[API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines),
needless word should be omitted, and  prepositional phrases should be made
argument labels. Also variable names should generally be lower (camel) case.

Therefore a better function name would be

```
public func longestBinaryGap(for n: Int) -> Int
```

Also variable names should not contain type information, that applies
for example to

```
var arrayOfIndexes: [Int]
```

#### Simplifying your approach

Let's start with `func getCurrentBinaryGapFor()`, that looks unnecessary
complicated. Without additional local variables it can be written as

```
func getCurrentBinaryGapFor(_ array:[Int]) -> Int {
    if array.count >= 2 {
        return array[array.count - 1] - array[array.count - 2] - 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

In the main function,

```
let currentBinaryGap = getCurrentBinaryGapFor(arrayOfIndexes)
if arrayOfIndexes.count == 2 {
    longestBinaryGap = currentBinaryGap
} else if index > 2 {
    if currentBinaryGap > longestBinaryGap {
        longestBinaryGap = currentBinaryGap
    }
}
```

can be simplified to

```
let currentBinaryGap = getCurrentBinaryGapFor(arrayOfIndexes)
if currentBinaryGap > longestBinaryGap {
    longestBinaryGap = currentBinaryGap
}
```

and the loop

```
var index = 0
for char in binaryString {
    if char == "1" {
        // ... do something ...
    }
    index += 1
}
```

can be written as

```
for (index, char) in binaryString.enumerated() where char == "1" {
    // ... do something ...
}
```

Only the last two elements of `arrayOfIndexes` are used in the program.
I would

- either store all positions of ones in the array first, and then determine
  the longest run from that array once,
- or use two variables for the recent two positions instead of an array.

In either case, a separate function to compute the current gap seems
unnecessary.

Summarizing the changes so far, the function would look like this:

```
public func longestBinaryGap(for n: Int) -> Int {
    var bitPositions: [Int] = [] // Positions of all `1` bits in `n`
    let binaryRepr = String(n, radix:2) //

    for (index, char) in binaryRepr.enumerated() where char == "1" {
        bitPositions.append(index)
    }

    var longestGap: Int = 0
    if bitPositions.count >= 2 {
        for i in 0...bitPositions.count - 2 {
            let gap = bitPositions[i + 1] - bitPositions[i] - 1
            if gap > longestGap {
                longestGap = gap
            }
        }
    }

    return longestGap
}
```

Using Swift's functional methods this could be written as

```
public func longestBinaryGap(for n: Int) -> Int {
    let binaryRepr = String(n, radix: 2) //

    let bitPositions = binaryRepr.enumerated()
        .filter { $0.element == "1" }
        .map { $0.offset }

    let longestGap = zip(bitPositions, bitPositions.dropFirst())
        .map { $1 - $0 - 1 }
        .max() ?? 0

    return longestGap
}
```

which looks elegant, but is actually a bit slower than the previous version.

#### Boosting the performance

Your approach is \$ O(d) \$ (in time and memory), where \$ d \$ is the 
number of digits in \$ n \$. That seems very good since any solution must
somehow traverse all digits of the given number.

As said above, the memory usage can be reduced to \$ O(1) \$ by keeping
only the last two bit positions, instead of using an array.

However, much time can be saved by *not* converting the integer to a string.
The binary digits of a number can be determined efficiently in pure
integer arithmetic.

That leads to the following implementation (essentially a Swift version
of [Find the binary gap of a number N](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159650/find-the-binary-gap-of-a-number-n/159678#159678)),
which is considerably faster:

```
public func longestBinaryGap1(for n : Int) -> Int {

    if n <= 0 {
        return 0
    }

    var n = n // Make a mutable copy
    // Remove trailing zeros:
    while n % 2 == 0 {
        n /= 2
    }

    var longestGap = 0
    var gap = 0
    repeat {
        n /= 2
        if n % 2 == 0 {
            // Current bit is `0`: increase gap size.
            gap += 1
        } else {
            // Current bit is `1`: check current gap, then reset.
            if gap > longestGap {
                longestGap = gap
            }
            gap = 0
        }
    } while n > 0

    return longestGap
}
```

And it gets even faster if we use the “find first bit set”
function `ffsl()` (which might take advantage of compiler intrinsics):

```
public func longestBinaryGap2(for n : Int) -> Int {

    var n = n // Make a mutable copy
    let firstPosition = ffsl(n)
    if firstPosition == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    n = n >> firstPosition

    var longestGap = 0
    while n > 0 {
        let position = Int(ffsl(n))
        if position - 1 > longestGap {
            longestGap = position - 1
        }
        n = n >> position
    }

    return longestGap
}
```

#### Benchmark

My simple benchmark:

```
let M = 1_000_000

do {
    var sum = 0
    let start = Date()
    for n in 1...M { sum += longestBinaryGap(for: n) }
    let end = Date()
    print(sum, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}
```

On a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 (with the program compiled in Release mode, i.e.
with optimizations), I measured approximately:

- Your original code: 3.3 seconds
- `longestBinaryGap1()`: 0.08 seconds
- `longestBinaryGap2()`: 0.04 seconds

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your detailed review! I just wanted to find the gap, longest gap, and adding `1` bits in one for loop, that is why I used an array to do so. Your solutions seem much faster!