# Find largest binary gap of a number N

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

I have picked up a problem from Codility website and tried to work it out.

A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the binary representation of N.

Write a function:

`class Solution { public int solution(int N); }`

that, given a positive integer N, returns the length of its longest binary gap. The function should return 0 if N doesn't contain a binary gap.

I would appreciate guidance of how to refactor it and what to look for in terms of efficiency?

Optimisation I'd like to achieve would be, less type conversion, no zero items in the list, would there be a better way to find the max number in a list, or .Sort(); is good enough?

Any ideas welcome, thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace rec
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FindGap(777)); // 
        }

        public static int FindGap(int number)
        {
            string toBinary = Convert.ToString(number, 2);

            char[] toChar = toBinary.ToCharArray();

            string previous = "";
            string current = "";
            int count = 0;
            int answer = 0;
            List<int> lastGap = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < toChar.Length; i++)
            {
                if (toChar[i].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    // temp becomes 1
                    current = toChar[i].ToString();

                    if (current == "1")
                    {
                        lastGap.Add(count);
                        count = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (toChar[i].ToString() == "0" && current == "1")
                {
                    current = "0";

                    count++;

                    previous = current;
                }
                else if (toChar[i].ToString() == "0" && previous == "0")
                {
                    current = "0";
                    count++;
                    previous = current;
                }
            }
            lastGap.Sort();
            answer = lastGap.Last();

            if (answer > 1)
            {
                return answer;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please provide a (possibly abbreviated) challenge description with your code review request. There may be subtleties not covered by the short description in the question title.

Comment: @t3chb0t You have changed the question to mention only positive numbers. This makes my answer completely irrelevant :-)

Comment: @dfhwze are you sure you mean me? I've just added one tag. Mhmm.... I don't usually edit programming-challenges as I'm not a fan ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t the edit makes it look as if you added the entire paragraph "A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the binary representation of N."

Comment: @dfhwze It was OP who added additional description that was missing.

Comment: @t3chb0t Well, it's crucial information, I wish I had known in advance :-) thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher - I actually refactored my code without using either of the suggested ways, so I requested further examination and suggestions as it is as one user mentioned, the code looks large and complex unnecessary. Can I put the refactored one instead the original one please? Again it isn't based on feedback.

Comment: Just read the provided link to know what you are allowed to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just looking for the longest stretch of zeros you don't need to use a list at all. You just iterate through the binary representation until you find a stretch of zeros. If you hit a new high score, you can overwrite the old high score with the new one and keep moving forward, forgetting about the past.

This is called a "greedy algorithm."

```
    public static int FindGap(int number)
    {
        string binaryRep = Convert.ToString(number, 2);

        int maxGapSize = 0;
        int currGapSize = 0;

        foreach(char ch in binaryRep)
        {
            if (ch == '0')
            {
                currGapSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                maxGapSize = Math.Max(currGapSize, maxGapSize);
                currGapSize = 0;
            }
        }

        return maxGapSize;
    }
```

If you want to get really fancy, you don't even need to convert the number to a string. You can use bit shifts to "iterate" through the bits in the number. The number 9 is 1001 in binary. Shift the bits over one, and you've got 100. Shift it over again, and you've got 10. You can use modulus operations to see if the least significant digit is 0 or 1.

This is just a fancy way to repeatedly divide by 2. In fact, you could solve this problem by dividing by 2 instead but this way works as well. (There's also probably a more terse way to write this, but this is perfectly efficient.)

```
    public static int FindGap2(int number)
    {
        int maxGapSize = 0;
        int currGapSize = 0;

        if (number == 0)
            return 0;

        while (number % 2 == 0)
            number = number >> 1;

        while (number > 0)
        {
            if(number%2 == 0)
            {
                currGapSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                maxGapSize = Math.Max(currGapSize, maxGapSize);
                currGapSize = 0;
            }
            number = number >> 1;
        }

        return maxGapSize;
    }
```

Comment: I was answering this way (the chars alternative) then i thought: this is reinventing the wheel, and now your comment "this is called a grredy algorithm" made me think: maybe that website is doing an introduction to regex !
Probably this is what they wanted .

Comment: @L.Trabacchin This does not work for strict negative integers. It could work if you convert the int bytes to an uint and work on this value instead. var n = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(number), 0);

Comment: @dfhwze there's no requirement for negative integers, on contrary it's been said to create a function for positive integers.

Comment: @Slothario, the greedy algorithm seems so easy. I wasn't aware at the time for Math.Max, therefore I have taken a long path.. do you mind, giving solution for the same algorithm without using Math.Max, just the logic I guess around comparing curr to max? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Slothario I would appreciate if you slice and dice my solution. I already know about Math.Max which makes the solution easier. I still try to understand how to bit shifting works, I also wasnt aware that binary operations are supported although I had to assume it.. But say you don't know about `Math.Max` and `>>` how would you go about it?

Comment: @Slothario, I can now see I have used double quotations marks around a char which is not ideal. I will try to refactor as much as I can and send it back for feedback.

Comment: @Slothario, the way I was thinking about it is to store all gaps in a list and then take out the largest, I see this is redundant operation as we are only interested at the largest which we can compare at each step and update..

Comment: @slothario is for some reason you could not access Math.Max you could just write your own: int32 Max(int32 a, int32 b) => a > b ? a : b; one line :)

Comment: @dfhwze sorry but this does work, i would just had a guard using UInt since the requirement is for positive integers... also it would not make much sense to convert int to uint, there is many binary representation. I think the requirements are kinda wrong (i think they wrote like that for simplicity), should ask just to find the gap in a sequence of 0 and 1... that is the point, not to learn how numbers are represented

Comment: @L.Trabacchin You can check my answer below to see it does not work for negative integers. The solution with a guard is a safe one, no doubt. But I understood that the problem was to find the gaps on any Int32. In this case, negative numbers had to be transformed first to UInt32.

Comment: I didn't realize he corrected the question, made you start with harder prerequisite

Comment: I just added the missing explanatory parts, which could have not been deducted from the title itself, he was just too quick to answer, as I have edited in between 5 minutes from original post :)

Comment: @Kris Make it 4 minutes next time! :-p. It was a fun challenge to include negative numbers anyway.

Comment: @Kris You don't need Math.Max(). You can use the inline solution L.Trabacchin mentioned, or even a simple if statement. I.e., `if(currGapSize > maxGapSize) currGapSize = maxGapSize`. I prefer Math.Max just for style reasons, but either case is totally fine. If you want to get really good at this style of problem, I encourage you to take a brief tutorial on bit operations and remember things like Math.Max! It will make you a stronger coder and interviewer.

Comment: Indeed, Math.Max is definitely part of my arsenal now thanks to you, thanks for the support @Slothario

Answer (score 5):

I think that part of the exercise is to make you re-invent the wheel just to learn that documentation is your friend, discovering something you just did already existed, in your case you really wrote everything also the `Math.Max`.

Part to become a good programmer is find a way to make your code reusable, so one BIG advice is refactor your code in a way that small functionality can be reused, in fact you could write your own separate function to do that.

```
Class Math 
{
    static Int32 Max(Int32 a, Int32 b) => a > b ? a : b;
}
```

But as i said an even bigger part of becoming a good programmer is learn to read the documentation, and avoid reinventing the wheel, because the wheel must be mantained, and could become hard. [Framework doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.math.max)

So, what about considering `System.Text.RegularExpressions` ?

[Amazing resource to learn all the superpowers they come with](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

If i understood right `000000010000100000` should return `4`, the initial bytes and the end ones are not took in account since they are not surrounded by ones.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 0u; i <= 5000u; i++)
            {
                var binaryRepresentation = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
                Console.WriteLine($"{i} => {binaryRepresentation} : {GetLongestAmountOfConsecutiveZeros(binaryRepresentation)}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static readonly Regex BinaryGapRegex = new Regex("1(0+)1", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        private static Byte GetLongestAmountOfConsecutiveZeros(String bits)
        {
            var matches = BinaryGapRegex.Matches(bits).Cast<Match>();
            var successingMatches = matches.Where(x => x.Success);
            var successingMatchesWithGroup = successingMatches.Where(x => x.Groups[1].Success /* Group 0 is the whole match with also the ones, group one is just the brackets part*/);
            var eachGroupLength = successingMatchesWithGroup.Select(x => /* Will never be longet than 32 */ (Byte)x.Groups[1].Value.Length);
            var longestGroup = !eachGroupLength.Any() ? Byte.MinValue : eachGroupLength.Max();
            return longestGroup;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is Code Review where we review code and provide suggestions on how to improve the code can you make some observations about the Posters code? Your answer might be very good on stack overflow but it isn't really meeting the goals of code review. Please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: sorry i come exactly from stackoverflow... Could I say that the poster code is very long and complicated while this can be achieved in a easier shorter way using a different approach?

Comment: That would be a start in the correct direction.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to convert the integer into a string. That's too expensive in terms of CPU usage and memory consumption.

As I [answered in a Java question on the same topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/217515) a few days ago, there's a simple solution using only integer arithmetics. That solution can be easily translated into C#.

Answer (score 3):

### Review

The initial question did not state it had to work only for positive integers. But after an edit, it does, rendering my answer moot. Anyway, I leave my answer up for those how are interested in an altered solution to work for all integers, regardless of sign.

> ```
> public static void Main()     
> {
>     // 11111111111111111111111111110011
>     Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(-13, 2)); 
>     // 0 -> incorrect         
>     Console.WriteLine(FindGap(-13));  
> }
> ```

After proposed fix:

```
public static void Main()   
{
    // 11111111111111111111111111110011
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(-13, 2)); 
    // 2 -> correct
    Console.WriteLine(FindGap(-13));    
}
```

FindGaps with binary arithmetic works also for strict negative numbers if we first translate the `int` to `uint`.

> ```
> public static int FindGap(int number)
>     {
>         ..
>
>         if (number == 0)
>             return 0;
>
>         ..
>     }
> ```

```
public static int FindGap(int number)
    {
        ..
        //var n = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(number), 0);
        var n = unchecked((uint)number); // even better approach

        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
       ..
    }
```

---

### Proposed Solution

```
public static int FindGap(int number)
    {
        int maxGapSize = 0;
        int currGapSize = 0;
        var n = unchecked((uint)number);

        if (n == 0)
            return 0;

        while (n % 2 == 0)
            n = n >> 1;

        while (n > 0)
        {
            if(n%2 == 0)
            {
                currGapSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                maxGapSize = Math.Max(currGapSize, maxGapSize);
                currGapSize = 0;
            }
            n = n >> 1;
        }

        return maxGapSize;
    }
```

---

### Remarks

Int32 storage in C#:

> In addition to working with individual integers as decimal values, you
> may want to perform bitwise operations with integer values, or work
> with the binary or hexadecimal representations of integer values.
> Int32 values are represented in 31 bits, with the thirty-second bit
> used as a sign bit. Positive values are represented by using
> sign-and-magnitude representation. Negative values are in two's
> complement representation. This is important to keep in mind when you
> perform bitwise operations on Int32 values or when you work with
> individual bits. In order to perform a numeric, Boolean, or comparison
> operation on any two non-decimal values, both values must use the same
> representation.

[About bit-shifting in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)

- If the first operand is of type int or long, the right-shift operator performs an **arithmetic shift**: the value of the most significant bit (the sign bit) of the first operand is propagated to the high-order empty bit positions. That is, the high-order empty bit positions are set to zero if the first operand is non-negative and set to one if it's negative.
- If the first operand is of type uint or ulong, the right-shift operator performs a **logical shift**: the high-order empty bit positions are always set to zero.

This means that -1 is represented as `11111111111111111111111111111111`. If we would allow `>>` on this value, we would get the value back, causing an infinite loop in your flow at `n = n >> 1;`. By converting the storage of the bytes from `int` to `uint` (is not the same as casting), we can perform all bit operations as expected. Hence, `var n = unchecked((uint)number);`.

Comment: I would then proceed to explain why it does not work with negative numbers, and how they are represented, so he can understand why converting them to Strings is not the same as they are in memory

Answer (score 2):

If you see the below code, I reduced few of statements which you used and that will improve the code performance.

I can see you have used multiple `ToString` calls which will highly consume memory.

We can use `HashSet` instead of `List` to store the counted binary gaps which will avoid the duplicated counts.

`for` loops are better instead of `foreach` loop - `for` loop works faster.

I believe this code block is more clear, easier to understand and more efficient.

This is working 100%, verified and test cases all passed

```csharp
    
public static int FindGap(int N) {
        
   var binaryValue = Convert.ToString(N, 2);
       
   var L = binaryValue.Length;
   var bLength = 0;
   var bArray = new List<int>();  //new HashSet<int>()

   for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
     
      if (binaryValue[i] == '0') {              
        
         bLength++;
         if ((L > i + 1) && binaryValue[i + 1] == '1'){ //Check the next index value is one              
            bArray.Add(bLength);
            bLength = 0;
         } 

         //Ex: 1000 (binary gaps is zero)
         if (L - 1 == i) { //Check the last index value is zero              
            bLength = 0;
            bArray.Add(bLength);
         }                
      }            
   }
   return  bArray.Count > 0 ? bArray.Max() : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective is that you can imagine all process. This is not the best solution but the point is where the algorithm has to go.

```
public int solution(int N) {

    var longestGap="";        
    var toBin=Convert.ToString(N,2);

    var items=toBin.Split('1');

    foreach(var item in items){
        bool isGap=toBin.Contains("1"+item+"1");
        if(isGap&&item.Length>longestGap.Length){
            longestGap=item;
        }
    }
    return longestGap.Length;
}
```