# Find largest binary gap of a number N improved

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

This is a follow-up question based on the [original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220865) one. Could you please see the updated and refactored version and point at things to be improved in term of logic or efficiency?

I have now know as I have been made aware about the Greedy Algorithm; Math.Max and binary shifting which deal more gracefully with the task, however, if I were in a position to be unaware of them and this is the code I managed to write, what's your thoughts on it?

```
    public static int FindGap(int number)
    {
        string toBinary = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
        char[] toChar = toBinary.ToCharArray();

        char previous = '0';
        char current = '0';
        int maxGap = 0;
        int answer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < toChar.Length; i++)
        {
            if (toChar[i] == '1')
            {
                current = toChar[i];

                // keep last/latest largest gap as an answer
                if (answer < maxGap)
                {
                    answer = maxGap;
                }

                // reset if 1 appeared and start counting next gap
                maxGap = 0;
            }
            if ((toChar[i] == '0' && current == '1') || (toChar[i] == '0' && previous == '0'))
            {
                current = '0';
                maxGap++;
                previous = current;
            }
        }

        if (answer != 0)
        {
            return answer;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The code still creates a string although this is not needed. You should try the code from my answer on the previous question. It is much more efficient.

Comment: @RolandIllig: The OP states that yours and other suggestions are ignored on purpose. I'm not claiming that the justification is particularly reasonable.

Comment: Long story short, I wanted to see my solution improved with the approach I have undertaken initially, without knowing what was already invented to support me in resolving such problems. It was important for me to see that I can do the Convert.ToString() inside the foreach loop and also that I have failed the obvious binary logic. To me that helps a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I were in a position to be unaware of them and this is the code I
>   managed to write, what's your thoughts on it?

- No need to call `ToCharArray()` because you can iterate over the chars of a string as well
- By using an `else if` instead of the second `if` you won't need to check for `toChar[i] == '0'` but basically you only need a `else`.
- Using a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop seems more natural for this task.
- The returning of the `answer` can be simply `return answer;`
- Because `ToString(int, 2)` strips leading `'0'` you can remove both `current` and `previous`.

Summing up it could look like so

```
public static int FindGap(int number)
{
    int maxGap = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    foreach(var c in Convert.ToString(number, 2))
    {
        if (c == '1')
        {
            if (answer < maxGap)
            {
                answer = maxGap;
            }
            maxGap = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            maxGap++;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew I was missing obvious things such as.. binary work, which translates to if and else.. This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. I will work out all suggested ways of going about it, with Math.Max, binary shift and what @Roland Illig suggested. This is a great way for learning.